# How can I ensure paragraph text in a figure has no side effects?

Tags: floats, indentation, paragraphs

I want to include a centred image with a caption and a paragraph above it (on the same page). To achieve this, I've got roughly the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        My paragraph

        \centering

        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my_image}

        \vspace*{-4mm}
        \caption*{My caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My current solution to the problem, as can be seen above, is to include the paragraph within the figure. I place the centering after the paragraph text to ensure the image is centred but not the paragraph. As it is currently, though, the paragraph doesn't utilise paragraph indentation: the first line of text is flush with the left margin. I am unaware if there are any other side effects to this implementation. How can I ensure that paragraph text within a figure behaves as regular paragraph text?

Comment: Using paragraph within the figure environment goes against the idea of figure environment. You are already forcing the position of this float with float package and H option; Then why not simply write the paragraph above the figure environment?